# Retornando erro em função inserir

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, singleton

Bom dia. Minha função está retornando um erro, mas não sei o que quer dizer, usei o padrão Singleton para fazer, portanto postarei 2 códigos:

```
<?php
    class IndicadoDAO{
        private $idIndicado;
        private $nome;
        private $email;
        private $telefone;
        private $curso;

        public function getidIndicado(){
            return $this->idIndicado;
        }
        public function getNome(){
            return $this->nome;
        }
        public function getEmail(){
            return $this->email;
        }
        public function getTelefone(){
            return $this->telefone;
        }
        public function getCurso(){
            return $this->curso;
        }
        public function setidIndicado($idIndicado){
            $this->idIndicado = $idIndicado;
        }
        public function setNome($nome){
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }
        public function setEmail($email){
            $this->email = $nome;
        }
        public function setTelefone($telefone){
            $this->telefone = $telefone;
        }
        public function setCurso($curso){
            $this->curso = $curso;
        }
    }
?>
```

---

```
<?php
     require_once('conexao.php');
     require_once('indicadoDAO.php');
     function inserirIndicado(indicadoDAO $indicado) {
        try{
        $sql = ("INSERT INTO indicado (nome, email, telefone, curso)
                VALUES(:nome, :email, :telefone, :curso)");

        $bau = Conexao::getConectar()->prepare($sql);
        $bau->bindValue(":nome", $indicado->getNome());
        $bau->bindValue(":email", $indicado->getEmail());
        $bau->bindValue(":telefone", $indicado->getTelefone());
        $bau->bindValue(":curso", $indicado->getCurso());
        return $bau->exec();
    } catch(PDOException $error){
            echo ("Erro encontrado") . $error->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

porém quando chamo a função ela dá erro, código dá pagina que está com erro a seguir:

```
<?php
    require_once('conexao.php');
    require_once('indicado.php');
    require_once('participante.php');

     $pdo = Conexao::getConectar();
     $pdo->beginTransaction();
     inserirIndicado();
     inserirParticipante();
     $pdo->rollBack();
?>
```

Resultado do erro: na linha 4, fala que passa nenhum parâmetro nelas //  
Too few arguments to function inserirIndicado(), 0 passed in

Alguém poderia me explicar o que está de errado na linha 4?

**Linha 4: function inserirIndicado(indicadoDAO $indicado) {
...
}**

Comment: A sua função `inserirIndicado` espera um parâmetro, `inserirIndicado(indicadoDAO $indicado)`, mas quando está chamando-a você não informa seu valor.

Comment: Mas em baixo nos getNome() getEmail() etc, ele não pegaria e guardaria em $indicado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está na linha `inserirIndicado();`, a função inserirIndicado espera receber uma instancia de `indicadoDAO`:

Você pode instanciar a classe com o código `$indicado = new indicadoDAO();` e então passa-lo a função: `inserirIndicado($indicado);`

```
<?php
    require_once('conexao.php');
    require_once('indicado.php');
    require_once('participante.php');

     $pdo = Conexao::getConectar();
     $pdo->beginTransaction();
     inserirIndicado();<------------------
     inserirParticipante();
     $pdo->rollBack();
?>
```

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Obrigado edson, resolveu meu problema!

Comment: Opa, que bom. Até mais